# Get the difference between two values

Tags: postgresql, difference

I got totally stuck on comparing two tables and getting the difference between them

So here we go:
I got table a with the following columns
Name|Value|Date

and the second table b with the same columns

What i wanna do now is get the difference between the values like

Table a

Name|Value|Date

Test|3|2013-20-06

Table b

Name|Value|Date

Test|9|2013-20-06

What i wann get is the difference between the 3 and 9 so i would recieve 6

Any Idea how i'm able to get that from a query in my PostgreSQL-DB?

Comment: do you want to know if this specific column is different or do you want to know for all columns? Say if the Name changes or the Date? You want to know as well?

Comment: All i wanna know is the differenct between the numbers, and to get the Name|number|date outprinted

Comment: what i wanna recieve exactly is Test|6|2013-20-06

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Join the tables and select the difference:

```
select a.name, b.value - a.value, a.date 
from a inner join b on a.name = b.name and a.date = b.date
```